# How do I can differentiate the customer login and admin login in the firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am Developing an web app which is based upon React and firebase in that I am using email and password for signing in  and signup, so I want to differentiate the admin and customer.

How it possible in Firebase? Please suggest me to resolve my issues.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255622/how-to-create-different-user-groups-in-firebase/48255734#48255734