# Adding user to a single app within a firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase project consisting of multiple apps. And I want to add an user as viewer/editor to one of the apps. **Note that I do not want to share all the apps within project, but just one app**. So can anyone help me with this. I do not seem to find any option for this. All I could find is to add user role to the project, which will share all the apps to other user. I do not want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All user information in a project is shared between all apps in that project. There is no way to partition the user information for a specific app.

There are two common cases for this request:

1. The apps have nothing to do with each other. In this case you should put each app in its own project.
2. The apps grant access for different types of users. In this case you will need to build your own role-based access system on top of Firebase, and allow only user with the correct role to use each app.

Also see:

- [How to create different user groups in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255622/how-to-create-different-user-groups-in-firebase)
- [How to create two types of users(Client , Freelancer. for example) while Auth using firebase in a flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66011139/how-to-create-two-types-of-usersclient-freelancer-for-example-while-auth-us)
- more results from [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+create+two+types+of+users)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Your 1st point is correct in my case. The apps have nothing to do with each other, and someone before me in my company have created them all in one project. Now i need to share one of the apps to its real owner/client. What are the options i have? Do i have to set the firebase app again in a separate project? and release a new version of my mobile app? Is there a way to do this without loosing analytics data?

Comment: You'll need to create a new project, add the app to that, and then share that with the client. If you use the same GA account, it may show the data for both apps - but likely not as one project. Putting apps for different clients (or even different use-cases) in a single project is just not going to work. Sorry you had to find that out the hard way.